# Use of Apache Ignite in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ignite

What do I need to do to use Apache Ignite in an Eclipse project?

I don't want to use Maven; I have Apache Luna; and I just want to use the in-memory data grid.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: I'm not asking for any of those things.  I just want to know the specific steps required to use Ignite from within a non-Maven Eclipse project.  I don't see any documentation describing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are no steps specific with Apache Ignite. You will have to determine the whole set of required JARs including transitive dependencies and manually add them to your project. I would strongly recommend to use Maven or other dependency management tool. What is the reason for not using it?